# Managing multiple third party integrations

Tags: java

I am working on a supply chain management project which manages orders, shipments etc between buyers/suppliers. Application is created in spring boot, java. Buyers/Suppliers are referred as parties on the application. Each party can have multiple users. Parties have the option to sync data to and from external systems like quickbooks, shopify etc. Now we have created the integration to these systems but the requirement from some parties is to customise the requests while exporting data from our system to the external systems.

So suppose there are 10 fields in a request to create order on quickbooks. So some want to send only 8 fields in request, some want to send 10 but with different request values and so on.

Now to manage this requirement, I have thought of below approaches

1. To create an interface and have different implementations for different parties who want customisation and a default implementation in case no customisation is required. The issue I see with this is the management of files. If there are a lot of customisation, then the number of files will grow drastically.
2. To manage the request mappings in property files by specifying the target JSON property using XPATH and value as source object field and populate using reflection. First issue with this is reflection which might make the process slow and second is dynamic calculation. If someone wants the output value to be a combination of two different inputs then it would be a problem
3. Instead of creating separate implementations for each party for the integration, Maybe just handle the property mapping using if/else in code. This way there will only be one implementation and also mapping involving complexities can also be handled.

Is there a better way that I might be missing for this sort of a problem?